# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Xcode) strcpy C Prog

Tags: exc-bad-access

Pretty sure I am missing something simple but Xcode keeps spitting this error EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)

Here is the part of the program in question:

```
typedef struct hrow{
    char value[12];
}hashRow;

typedef struct hT{
    hashRow *rows;
}hashTable;

hashTable* populateHash(FILE *fPtr){

    int num, i;
    char strings[12]; // temp array for read-in string

    fscanf(fPtr,"%d",&num); // read in number of strings

    if(num < 1)
        return NULL;

    hashTable *table = (hashTable*)malloc(sizeof(hashTable)*num); // declare a table

    // copy each string into the hash table array
    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
        fscanf(fPtr,"%s",strings);
        strcpy(table->rows[i].value, strings);  // EXC_BAD_ACCESS HERE!!!!
    }

    return table;
}
```

Am I missing a malloc? Xcode also says that the function call argument is an uninitialized value (the strcpy line).

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: At no point do you ever initialize the `rows` pointer. What did you expect was going to happen?

Comment: for some reason, i thought initializing the *table pointer would also initialize rows. I added the malloc for rows and it works. Thanks